# MVC4 / IIS / Forms Authentication SSO issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, forms-authentication, session-cookies

I’ve got a weird intermittent issue with MVC4 / IIS / Forms Authentication.

I’ve got a pair of sites that pass control to each other using SSO. Most of the time the handover occurs correctly and the user is redirected to the next site as intended. However, in some cases, the user is asked to log in again, even though valid SSO information was sent across. The `SSO` method is decorated with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute and the *web.config* also has a location entry granting access to */account/sso* to all users.

It appears to occur when the destination site is being hit for the first time  - once the app pool is warmed up, the issue disappears.

Some other points:

1 both sites are .net 4, so there should not be any legacy encryption issues. 
 2. this issue happens quite rarely (<10% of the time) so the code itself *should* be sound
 3. Hosting is IIS 7.5 on win7x64 locally, and azure - happens in both places
 4. Seems to be browser independent

```
<location path="account/sso">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

[Authorize]
public class AccountController : BaseControllerTestable
{
    public AccountController()
        : base()
    {
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SSO(string AuthToken, string Target)
    {
        //SSO logic here

    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the logon screen presented when a new session starts?
How is the session timeout set for both web apps?
do they have different application pools? do these pools have a recycle setting?
did endable the performance counters of the sites and recorded relevant performance counters of the site like session timeout, recompilations?

Comment: Sounds like definitely not a code issue. My guess would be either cookie timeout if you use cookies, or app pool recycling. Put some tracing into your authentication logic, is SSO method being executed when the issue occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally resolved it (we'll only know for sure once we've had a good while without recurrence given that it was intermittent anyway)

A couple of factors came into play. Firstly I noticed a few static items (css+js files mostly) that were getting caught up in authentication loop even though they should be freely accessible, so I added a location rule in web.config to make sure they were allowed to anonymous users. I also added a route exception to ignore favicon.ico requests for good measure too. This seemed to stop the code from tripping over itself when authenticating for the first time. Finally, the reason the issue was intermittent was due to another bug where if there was any other sessions open (db driven) the issue didn't occur. this explained why the bug only happened early in the morning ie: all the sessions from the previous day had expired.

Answer (score 1):

You have an Authorize attribute on your Controller class which means that your SSO method would have AllowAnonymous and Authorize applied to it. In this instance the Authorize attribute looks like it needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

What is your **BaseControllerTestable**? Do you have any **authorization** attributes there? Your Base class will be instantiated firs before it will get to your other methods on the derived class. So if by any chance you have [**Authorize**] on the base controller that may be an issue for you.